# Permanently Alias a Tablename SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I have some old database things which are interconnected to some other systems, I have a new database configuration with table names that are somewhat different than the original older database - I want the older systems to still be able to update the database tables as if nothing changed so to speak.

I know in a query I can alias the table name - I am **not** looking for how to do that.

I want to set the alias in a more permanent fashion; is there a way to do this in SQL Server? If so how?

I had thought on adding a trigger to the original tables on insert, delete, update to accomplish this - but was hoping for something more elegant than to do this for each of the tables I have to do this with.

Comment: "Elegance" is probably not a part of any solution here. "What is possible" should be your focus followed by a serious investigation into the best path for your situation. It is not clear what your goal is and it is very concerning that you don't know exactly what "other systems" access the old table. How would you even begin to test this? A view is the obvious suggestion but this may not work depending on what the code in these other systems actually use. In that case you will need some form of bi-directional replication.

Comment: @SMor yes concerning to me that I don't know. I am not in charge of those systems, nor the one I am investigating to fix and then provide a better solution. On what information I do have, that is what I need to go on for now. What I do see is no relation constraints on related tables, poorly structured tables, lack of normalization, bad naming structure, bad data-typing etc..  fixing things with out eliminating the old - in order to transition to newer system and doing it while the system is live. Not ideal.

Answer (score 4):

If the structure of the tables are identical, you can use [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
CREATE SYNONYM <new_table_name>
               FOR <old_table_name>;
```

Otherwise you'll need (updatable) views, possibly with `INSTEAD OF` triggers implementing the translation.

Comment: Structure is similar , this is a process upgrade - someone initially designed this old database and hence the table (very poorly ). I need to be able to determine what other systems in the company are accessing the database and manipulating the data (lots of spider webs). So I need to be able leave fields in place while implementing a newer and better structure and migrate overtime. Not the best but I don't seem to have a choice.

Comment: I'm not sure if that comment means this answers your question or not? Perhaps you could clarify if it doesn't This is certainly not a new problem - makeing changes to a system while trying not to break old stuff that you don't even know exists.

Comment: @Ken: Alright, then views it is... But then I'd also not really describe that as a mere permanent "alias".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view, which in many ways will appear to behave like a table.

```
create view aliasname 
as 
select fields1, field2 
from originalname
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The problem is the table gets updated remotely and I do want the data in the new datatable structure. The Tables are similar in structure but not exact duplicate - the new table has other fields - keeping existing fields, trying to convert on the fly and phase out old things gradually ..as we become aware of what systems are directly connected and what things are modifying this.
Views are not insertable and also defeats the purpose my new table has a different tablename than the existing table ..

Comment: You can create the view using the fields that the legacy system understands (i.e. you can omit any newly added fields and you can alias field names that have changed.